# Iterate through a list argument in Lilypond define-scheme-function

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

I'm trying to write my first `define-scheme-function` in Lilypond, and I'm stuck. I'm wanting to output a variable number of handbell 'echo' notations within a single measure.

This is working for a static number (2-4):

```
echoTwoThreeFour = #(define-scheme-function
 (halign)
 (number?)
 #{ \markup { \halign #halign \center-column {⮍ 2} \center-column {⮍ 3} \center-column {⮍ 4} } #}
 )

<c e g c>1 -$(echoTwoThreeFour -3)
```

This outputs:
[image]

However, I'd really like to send as an argument a list of beat numbers `(list 2 3 4)` so that I can use a single function for variable numbers of echoes, called like:

`<c e g c>1 -$(echoVariable (list 2 3 4) -3)`

How can I iterate through a list of numbers within a scheme function and output the appropriate markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example like this. `map` creates a list of function results for each entry of a list. This can be used to create the individual markups. Then we simply make a line markup from this list of markups.

```
echoN =
#(define-scheme-function
 (halign iterations)
 ((number? -3) list?)
 (let* ((marks (map (lambda (c) #{ \markup\center-column {⮍ #(number->string c) } #}) iterations))
        (basemup (make-line-markup marks)))
   #{ \markup \halign #halign #marks #}))

{ <c e g c>1 -\echoN #'(1 2 3) }
```

Edit: But I think you are actually using `\halign` for the purpose of `\hspace`. You’d probably want to do

```
echoN =
#(define-scheme-function
 (space iterations)
 ((number? 3) list?)
 (let ((marks (map (lambda (c) #{ \markup\center-column {⮍ #(number->string c) } #}) iterations)))
   (make-line-markup (cons (make-hspace-markup space) marks))))
```

Note that this can then also be called with this nice scheme-free syntax

```
{ <c e g c>1 -\echoN 2 1,2,3 }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Lazy! I will try this out. Thanks for the hint on halign vs. hspace. I'm guessing I have lots of such things going on in my first few scores, due to copying/pasting without fully understanding.

Comment: Perhaps someday my eyes will be able to read scheme/lisp without so much effort. Are you missing a parameter in the first snippet `-\echoN #'(1 2 3)`?

Comment: @Mark See here https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/extending/scheme-function-definitions.html the stuff about optional arguments.